# Change at runtime the background of a table added to a stage in the constructor

Tags: libgdx

I need at runtime to reload a background of a table added to a stage (the user can change it at runtime).

I'm doing this but the background will change only when I switch back from another Screen or reopen my game.

**MyGame.java**:

```
String backgroundFileName = "background1.jpg";
public class MyGame extends Game {
    public void create() {
        ...
        
        this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    }
    
    public void handleChoosenBackground(String _backgroundFileName) {
        backgroundFileName = _backgroundFileName;
        
        if(getScreen() instanceof MainMenuScreen) {
            ((MainMenuScreen)getScreen()).reloadBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainMenuScreen.java**:

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    Stage stage;
    Table table;
    
    TextureRegionDrawable textureRegionDrawableBackground;
    
    public MainMenuScreen(final MyGame game) {
        ...
        stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
        
        textureRegionDrawableBackground = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(game.backgroundFileName)));
        
        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.setBackground(textureRegionDrawableBackground);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }
    
    public void reloadBackground() {
        textureRegionDrawableBackground = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(game.backgroundFileName)));
        table.setBackground(textureRegionDrawableBackground);
        
        // log prints here, so this method is reached, with the correct new backgroundFileName
    }
}
```

I also tried this on MyGame class but it seems that does nothing because MainMenuScreen is already the active screen:

```
setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
```

If, instead, I set `textureRegionDrawableBackground` to `null`, it works showing a white background:

```
public void reloadBackground() {
    textureRegionDrawableBackground = null; // <<<<<
    table.setBackground(textureRegionDrawableBackground);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I didn't run `table.pack()` once I finished putting all the things into the table - apparently the background size doesn't automatically resize to the table size, and you need to tell it to do so.
Hope that solves your problem :)